# SpringBoot 2.7 : Configuration to Make All the Controllers to Produce and Consume JSON

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

Currently we have below annotation on all the controller methods to ensure APIs produces and consumes JSON am wondering if there is any config change that I can do so that the default behavior will be JSON for `produces` and `consumes`

```
@RequestMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the `@RestController` annotation to the controller class

You don't need to configure it on every method

Comment: If you also want to return json in a uniform format, you can do so

`ResponseBodyAdvice ` and adds the `@RestControllerAdvice` annotation on the implementation class